# RequireAny apache2 error

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-auth

I am trying to use RequireAny to allow acces to a site from either a certain IP or with a certain username. However, when I try to run apache I get the following error:

```
Invalid command '<RequireAny', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The part of my apache file with authentication looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/web/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Options
    AcceptPathInfo On
    AuthName "Protected Site"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd

    <RequireAny>
            Require user dev
            Require ip 71.198.111.188
    </RequireAny>

        #Order allow,deny
        #allow from all
</Directory>
```

Why am I getting an error when using RequireAny in this case?

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<RequireAny>` and `Require` directives that you're trying to use were [added in Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html) and are in the [`mod_authz_core`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html) module. They are not available in Apache 2.2.